# Build OData service V2 with VS2017

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, odata

I need to create a service that publishes data in OData V2 format because the system that consumes that data only accept this format.
I made a project based on WEB API 2 and EF and it's running, but it's version 3.
After some research, I found that it could be possible to change that version, with the following code:

```
ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
var odataVersion2 = new Version(1, 0);
builder.DataServiceVersion = odataVersion2;
builder.MaxDataServiceVersion = odataVersion2;
```

The edmx file is changed

```
<edmx:DataServices m:DataServiceVersion="1.0" m:MaxDataServiceVersion="1.0" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
```

but the schemas seems to be wrong.
For instance, I have one, taken from Northwind OData service

```
<Schema Namespace="NorthwindModel" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/09/edm">
```

and my file has

```
<Schema Namespace="ODataServer.Models" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm">
```

Is there any way to truly indicate that the OData service must follow V2 specs?
Or to force to use the right schemas?

Thank you in advance.
Adrián

Answer (score 0):

Well, I was able to solve the problem.
Method "Register" should be like this:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();

    //Declare entities
    builder.EntitySet<Empleado>("Empleados");

    //Define verion
    Version odataVersion2 = new Version(2, 0);
    builder.DataServiceVersion = odataVersion2;
    builder.MaxDataServiceVersion = odataVersion2;

    IEdmModel edmModel = builder.GetEdmModel();
    edmModel.SetEdmVersion(odataVersion2);
    edmModel.SetEdmxVersion(odataVersion2);

    config.Routes.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "odata", edmModel);

    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Now the EDMX has the desired schemas.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<edmx:Edmx Version="1.0" xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx">
  <edmx:DataServices m:DataServiceVersion="2.0" m:MaxDataServiceVersion="2.0" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
    <Schema Namespace="ODataServer.Models" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/09/edm">
      <EntityType Name="Empleado">
        <Key>
          <PropertyRef Name="EmpleadoID" />
        </Key>
        <Property Name="EmpleadoID" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false" />
        <Property Name="NroLegajo" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false" />
        <Property Name="ApeNom" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" />
        <Property Name="FecIngreso" Type="Edm.DateTime" Nullable="false" />
        <Property Name="Email" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" />
        <Property Name="Proyecto" Type="Edm.String" />
      </EntityType>
    </Schema>
    <Schema Namespace="Default" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/09/edm">
      <EntityContainer Name="Container" m:IsDefaultEntityContainer="true">
        <EntitySet Name="Empleados" EntityType="ODataServer.Models.Empleado" />
      </EntityContainer>
    </Schema>
  </edmx:DataServices>
</edmx:Edmx>
```